# How to install libtopmenu-gtk modules

Tags: apt, software-installation, gtk, ubuntu-mate

I have a C++ program that uses SDL library. The program is working fine on OSX but not on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 bionic running on odroid.

The error is something like `no topmenu-gtk-module cannot be found`.  I tried to install topmenu as

```
sudo apt install libtopmenu-gtk*
```

but cannot be found in any repository.

How to install these libraries on Ubuntu Mate? Or which is the correct repository to be added?

Comment: Do you have clean installation of UM 18.04 or have upgraded from 16.04 LTS?

Comment: no I did an upgrade

Comment: @FranscesoBoi Then see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Both `topmenu-gtk2` and `topmenu-gtk3` packages [are not available for 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=topmenu-gtk&searchon=names).

You can override GTK modules for your application in the terminal with

```
GTK_MODULES="canberra-gtk-module" /path/to/your-app
```

or by editing its .desktop file

```
env GTK_MODULES="canberra-gtk-module" /path/to/your-app
```

---

As you have upgraded from Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS then it may be other issue (see [this post on ubuntu-mate.community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/problems-with-the-dropbox-icon-in-the-panel-um-18-04-1/17495/8?u=norbert_x) - you need to remove one file manually:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99mate-environment
```

and then reboot.

Comment: so is it sufficient to remove the file and skipping the lines above?

Comment: You can try both methods. File removal will fix future issues.

Comment: Removing the 99mate-environment file for me!  Only took another dist upgrade (18.04 -> 20.04) to figure this out.